# Image not found while trying to load gdal in python

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

```
    import gdal
  File "/Users/rit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "/Users/rit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/rit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rit/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmfhdf.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/rit/anaconda2/lib/libgdal.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I am having issues running a python script which uses gdal, getting the error above. How can I fix it? I am using python 2.7.11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broken references in Virtualenvs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs)

Comment: Check this question in another community of Stack Exchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44958/gdal-importerror-in-python-on-windows