# 'virtualenv' causing setup errors

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, python-3.4, python-3.5

I've been trying to use virtualenv for python but whenever I try to run the virtualenv venv command, I receive this error:

```
Using base prefix '/Users/me/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/me/venv/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.5m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/venv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/me/venv/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/me' (should be '/Users/me/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Before this I made sure I did

```
pip install virtualenv
```

And that was fine. Not sure how to solve this error. Also 'me' is my username

Update: I was able to fix this issue. The other post that others told me to look at didn't help. I had to reinstall anaconda to fix the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broken references in Virtualenvs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're a Mac user like me. This error typically occurs when you have updated the Python that you used to create the virtualenv. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs) tells you what you need to know, so I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate (because I didn't search for existing answers before I started this reply!)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by reinstalling anaconda