# `dyld: Library not loaded` error preventing virtualenv from loading

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I tried creating a virtual environment with python using the command `virtualenv venv` from Terminal, I got the following error:

```
Using base prefix '/Users/zacharythomas/anaconda3'
New python executable in /Users/zacharythomas/venv/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/zacharythomas/venv/bin/python
Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/zacharythomas/venv/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/zacharythomas' (should be '/Users/zacharythomas/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I'm not the first person to encounter a similar error -- I tried following [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25947333/3899919) recommendations and running:

```
gfind ~/.virtualenvs/my-virtual-env/ -type l -xtype l -delete
```

That didn't help. Nor did running `sudo virtualenv venv` to run commmand as a super user.

What should I investigate next?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had the exact same error message.  Ray Donnelly at Continuum Analytics Support Group provided the following solution, which resolved the issue for me:

> When you pip installed virtualenvwrapper, pip will have installed
> virtualenv for you as it is a dependency. Unfortunately, that
> virtualenv is not compatible with Anaconda Python. Fortunately, the
> Anaconda Distribution has a virtualenv that is compatible. To fix
> this:
>
> ```
> pip uninstall virtualenv
> conda install virtualenv
> ```

[can't get virtualenv to work with anaconda3 v4.3 on mac](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/XuXMiJLhMgk)

Comment: @Dave2e Got it, thanks for the pointers since I'm new to stackoverflow.  As it happened, I came across an actual answer to this question in the meanwhile.  So, I edited my original non-answer and replaced it with this.