# Tensorflow installation issue

Tags: macos, tensorflow

My computer already installed Python 3.5 with [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

`$ python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)`

I'm following the [Installation instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac). There are some errors show up when I want to specify my targetDirectory.

`$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow`

```
Using base prefix '/Users/UserName/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/UserName/tensorflow/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.5m.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/UserName/tensorflow/bin/python
Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/UserName/tensorflow/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/UserName/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages' (should be '/Users/UserName/tensorflow')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

How can I fix the environment issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`dyld: Library not loaded\` error preventing virtualenv from loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190984/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-preventing-virtualenv-from-loading)

Comment: Try installing `virtualenv` with `conda` instead of `pip`, as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190984/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-preventing-virtualenv-from-loading#answer-42706875).