# How to specify python version used to create Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

My Python virtual environments use `python3.6` when I create them using `virtualenv`

> `~ $ virtualenv my_env`

but I need to use `python3.5` as 3.6 is [not currently supported by `Opencv3`.](https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3/issues/21)

I've tried using the `--python=<py_version>` flag when creating a virtual environment but this doesn't work.

## How do I specify the python (3.x) version to install using `virtualenv` for Mac and/or Linux?

Comment: Have you installed Python 3.5 on your computer? You're right in passing the `--python` flag, so something else about your environment or invocation is wrong here. Can you give the error message?

Comment: Yesterday I tried running `conda install python=3.5` inside of my activated virtual environment thinking that this would change the python dist inside my env but instead it changed the local version. I changed back to 3.6 but now I run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190984/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-preventing-virtualenv-from-loading) but the answer there does not work for me. oh god what did I do

Comment: @CodyPiersall It seems that installing `miniconda` changed the path var to `/Users/.../miniconda3/bin:` which is incompatible with the python version `virtualenv` was using. Removing `/Users/.../miniconda3/bin` from the path fixes the issue but then I can't use `conda`... I know this is now a separate issue but any ideas how I can add it back to the path without messing up virtualenv?

Comment: I just want to give an hint for those using Windows(and using Powershell). In this case make sure to explicitly write the .exe, that is what I mean: virtualenv -p C:\PythonVersionFolder\Python.exe EnvName. Otherwise you could get the PermissionError: [WinError 5] denied Access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Assuming that you have installed `python3` or any desired version of Python (2.6, 2.7, 3.5, 3.6), Now while creating the virtual environment directly pass the python executable path. Hence here are few valid example

```
$ virtualenv new_p2_env # Creates a new default python environment (usually python 2)

$ virtualenv -p python3 new_p3_env # Creates a new default python3 (python3 must be a valid command i.e found in the PATH)
```

And last

```
# Directly point to any version of python binary, this can be even another virtualenv's bin/python. 
$ virtualenv -p /path/to/any/bin/python new_env
```

Comment: this just creates a virtual environment with `python3.6`. I want `python3.5`

Comment: You can easily find a way to uninstall `python3.6` and install `python3.5`. If you do have to keep multiple versions of python on the same machine, use tools like `pyenv` or `pythonbrew`

Comment: hey @itsneo thanks for the suggestions! Reading further into your comment would I be right in understanding that when you create a virtual env that `virtualenv` uses the local python version (2.x/3.x) specified in the `$PATH` and that there is no way to change the specific python version through the `virtualenv` command itself?

Comment: You can still create one directly mentioning the python executable path like this `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python35 env_name`

Comment: Complementing @nehem 's comment, which worked perfectly for me: to find out the python path, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589722)

Comment: You could also use your specific python identifier's name e.g. `virtualenv -p python3.9 venv`

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, I think you could use the specific version of Python itself to create the virtual environment. That way, you'll know for sure it's the correct version:

```
$ python3.5 -m venv test35
$ ./test35/bin/python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build ) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Reference at https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/venv.html

Comment: nice. yeah I ended up creating the venv with `conda`. Huge relief to have it all working now

Comment: If all your Python versions are simply called `python`, you can still refer to each one separately if you know the full path. So `/opt/srv/whatever/path/to/python345/bin/python -m venv test345` would create a virtual environment for Python 3.4.5 if you have it installed in that particular path.

Answer (score 8):

As of version 3.3, python includes a package named `venv`. However that package doesn't provide the same functionalities as the traditional `virtualenv` package.

`venv` allows creating virtual environments only for the version of python it's installed for.
`virtualenv` allows creating virtual environments for different versions of python by providing the path to the binary.

## Creating virtual envs for different versions of python:

So assuming one has python 2.7 and python 3.6 installed in `/path/to/` and wants to create the virtual env named respectively `env-py36` with python 3.6 and `env-py27` with python 2.7

```
# create a virtual env with python3's venv :
/path/to/python36/bin/python3 -m venv /my/python-venvs/env-py36
. /my/python-venvs/env-py36/bin/activate
# we're now running python 3's "env-py36" virtual env, we want to install the "virtualenv" package
pip install virtualenv
deactivate
# now use virtualenv to create a virtual environment for python 2.7
/my/python-venvs/env-py36/bin/virtualenv --python=/path/to/python27/bin/python /my/python-venvs/env-py27
```

## Using python 3.3+ venv

Python 3.3+ :

```
/path/to/python3/bin/python3 -m venv ENV_DIR
```

Python 3.3 to 3.5 (deprecated in 3.6+) :

```
/path/to/python3/bin/pyvenv ENV_DIR
```

## Sources:

- [Creating Virtual Environments](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments)
- [Python 3.3 venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
- [Python virtualenv package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Answer (score 7):

I working on all ubuntu and MacOS

> Ubuntu : `virtualenv -p python3.6 environment_file`
>
> Mac OS : `virtualenv -p python3.6 environment_file`

I think it be same

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue (and came here) but under Windows. Python 3.9 was installed on one system but it had issues with code developed under 3.7. I wanted to use a virtual environment to downgrade to 3.7 to help debug the issue.  Using **Python Launcher for Windows**:

```
py -3.7 -m venv my_env
```

in the python project folder did the trick for me.

Comment: wish I could up vote this more times because it took me a while to find this great solution

Answer (score 0):

Simple and direct solution:
Just see this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC9FBQnOv6o) and follow the python setup download instructions of a particular python version and then use virtualenv <folder_name> -p /python.exe
This command is also shown in the video too.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux:

Suppose you have python **3.8 (or higher)** installed on the system, but for a specific task, you need **python 3.7 (or lower)**. The best idea is (not to downgrade) to Create a virtual environment with python 3.7(or any 3.x, **change the commands below according to your desired version. Below is an implementation of a virtual environment with python 3.7**)

Steps:

1. Install python 3.7 and it’s virtual environment packages.

   `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev python3.7-venv`
2. Find out where your python 3.7 is located by this command:

   `which python3.7` (Should be something like /usr/bin/python3.7)
3. Create Virtual Environment in the Home directory.

   `cd`

   `mkdir virtual_env`

   `/usr/bin/python3.7 -m venv ~/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.7`

   `source ~/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.7/bin/activate`
4. `python --version` (Should be python 3.7 now)
5. Done. Python 3.7 can be used in this virtual environment. Type `which python`, you’ll see you have created python 3.7 in a virtual environment, rather than in the system globally.

   Run `deactivate` when you need to deactivate.

Answer (score 0):

Using anaconda we can create a virtual environment called "py35_env" with Python 3.5 version by running:

```
conda create --name py35_env python=3.5
```