# Python 3.5 create virtualenv with python2.7

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have Python 3.5 installed in my windows machine and that is the only version I have on my computer. I want to create a python2.7 virtual environment to try out a certain package. Is it possible to create a virtual environment with python2.7 binaries without installing Python 2.7 in my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a different Python interpreter, that interpreter needs to be on $PATH, which means a binary on your machine.

see --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45293556/6813490

Comment: That means I need to install python27?

Comment: yes indeed, although having multiple Python interpreters is not a hassle

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have your Python interpreter on $PATH, you can tell `virtualenv` where to find it. I found this blog post [Installing Multiple Python Versions on Windows Using Virtualenv](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/installing-multiple-python-versions-on-windows-using-virtualenv/) but the TL;DR is:

1. Open Command Prompt and enter `pip install virtualenv`.
2. Download the desired python version (do NOT add to PATH!), and remember the `path\to\new_python.exe` of the newly installed version.
3. To create a virtualenv, open Command Prompt and enter `virtualenv \path\to\env -p path\to\new_python.exe`.
4. To install packages:

   1. Activate virtualenv: open Command Prompt and enter `path\to\env\Scripts\activate.bat`.
   2. Install desired packages with `pip`.
   3. Deactivate with `deactivate`.

Note `python3 -m venv \path\to\env` doesn't seem to suppport the `-p` parameter, you have to use `virtualenv`.