# Specifying Python Version in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have installed python 3.6 at `/usr/bin/python3.6` and I am trying to create a virtualenv using this version of python.

I tried `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 testenv`
and then I activated the virtualenv with `source testenv/bin/activate`
however when I open the python shell it says the version is 2.7.12

Below is a screenshot
[image]

If the virtualenv is activated then shouldn't it be using Python 3.6? What am I missing here?

Comment: hmmm looks like this just happens for python3.6. python3.5 seems to work

Comment: If you just type /usr/bin/python3.6 in console, does it start Python 3.6 shell?

Comment: Also what is your virtualenv version?

Comment: @Olivier when I type /usr/bin/python3.6 it goes to the 2.7.12 shell.  I think there's something wrong with my python 3.6 installation

Comment: Yes. I am confused as to how this could have happened, but I would attempt reinstalling Python 3.6. Intriguing. Do you remember when and how you installed Python 3.6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify python version used to create Virtual Environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment)