# Why tensorflow is not installing using pip?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I want to install tensorflow using pip. I ran `pip install tensorflow` but it shows an error message given below:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from 
versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS? Which version of python?

If you are running a 32-bit version of python on Windows for example, tensorflow is not supported.

Also could be the case that your pip is not upgraded, in that case do:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Also if you are using python 3.7, not yet supported by tensorflow.

Comment: I am using windows. Python is 3.7 64 bit. If tensorflow does not support 3.7 then is there any way to install?

Comment: You can install 3.6 or any other version supported by tensorflow, and create a virtualenv using that version. Install tensorflow in that virtualenv, very easy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment?rq=1