# Under Python 3.7 Virtual env, how to install a program that only run on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, conda

I have a virtual env created under Python 3.7.
A main program can be installed and ran under Python 3.7.
However, this main program requires a side program that can be only installed under Python 2.7.

How to install this side program under the Conda virtual env (Python 3.7)?

On the other hand, I have installed the side program in a virtual env (Python 2.7). How to install the main program that requires Python 3.7 in this virtual env?

I am doing this on a Mac.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have a `.bat` file that can install python2.7, you may have to do some re-configuration to the current virtualenv to run py2.7.

Comment: Nope. I do not have the bat file.

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? What do you mean by _this main program requires a side program_ ?

Comment: install both the python versions. Call the respective programs with the absolute path of the respective python version

Comment: this may be helpful, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment/45293556#45293556)