# How can I set the latest python interpreter

Tags: python

I have many python versions installed. I need nevertheless that when using VSC the script be run by `python3.10.7`. I changed accordingly the interpreter in VSC to the latest python version. The latest python version, `python3.10.7`, is installed in the folder `/user/bin`, while the one which I get with `which python` is installed in a different folder, `home/myname/anaconda3/bin/python`. I will appreciate your help. I use `Ubuntu 20.4`. I do not have experience in using virtual environments. How do I change the interpreter to the latest one ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Virtual Environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) are your friend!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment

Comment: I do not want to use virtual environments.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use them?

Comment: I find them complicated. I do not have the time to go through them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by opening the Command Palette using Ctrl+Shift+P and enter Preferences: Open User Settings. Then set python.defaultInterpreterPath, which is in the Python extension section of User Settings, with the appropriate interpreter.

Comment: I have done it as I pointed out at my post. The VSC is linked to the latest version. In the terminal however, when I check for the version used, I get `python3.9.7` instead of what VSC is linked to, `python3.10.7`. In fact, when I run some code that is supported only in `3.10.7`, I get an error message, showing that the code is not run by the interpreter I want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).