# Unable to run python commands within virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am working with a Django project for a while now and at the start of the project, I created a virtualenv. I used the method from [this website](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/create-a-blank-django-project/).  And two months later, when I try to run any python related command, I get stuck with this error (below). I don't believe the error is with the virtual environment because I am able to activate it. For reference, the content of my bin is also below.

```
<!-- Error from the terminal -->
(command) python manage.py runserver
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
Referenced from: /Users/UzairVawda/Sites/DragonFeed/bin/python
Reason: image not found
[1]    87972 abort      python manage.py runserver

(command) python
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
Referenced from: /Users/UzairVawda/Sites/DragonFeed/bin/python
Reason: image not found
[1]    87891 abort      python

<!-- Content of my bin-->
total 176
drwxrwxrwx  3 UzairVawda  staff     96 Jul  2 10:16 __pycache__
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff   2093 Apr 12 11:46 activate
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff   1035 Apr 12 11:46 activate.csh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff   2189 Apr 12 11:46 activate.fish
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff   1137 Apr 12 11:46 activate_this.py
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    297 Apr 12 11:47 django-admin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    155 Apr 12 11:47 django-admin.py
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    264 Apr 12 11:46 easy_install
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    264 Apr 12 11:46 easy_install-3.6
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    251 Apr 12 12:12 gunicorn
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    253 Apr 12 12:12 gunicorn_paster
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    236 Apr 12 11:46 pip
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    236 Apr 12 11:46 pip3
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    236 Apr 12 11:46 pip3.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff      7 Jul  2 10:13 python -> python3
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff   2352 Apr 12 11:46 python-config
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff  25464 Apr 12 11:46 python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff      7 Jul  2 10:13 python3.6 -> python3
-rwxrwxrwx  1 UzairVawda  staff    243 Apr 12 11:46 wheel
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190984/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-preventing-virtualenv-from-loading

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs