# New Pipenv cause my previous virtualenvwrapper to break

Tags: python, pipenv, virtualenvwrapper

I worked on a previous project (let's call it A) using **virtualenvwrapper**. 

But after reading about **Pipenv**, I decided to use it for my new project (B).

Now, when I try to run project A I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
 Referenced from: ...virtualenvs/A/bin/python
 Reason: image not found
```

I saw other questions about this error, but there it was happening after updating Mac/Python versions. This is not the case for me :(

Can you please help?

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally installed pipenv from *inside* your virtualenvwrapper? Happenned to me once with some similar installations, and what helped was uninstalling the latter and then reinstalling from the root environment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! but I checked and it's not the case for me :)

Comment: You may want to check this out if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @ryan-marvin's comment I found the answer. It's in here - [Broken references in Virtualenvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs).

But the thing is, it's not exactly the same situation because for me, this command:
`ls -la ~/.virtualenvs/my-virtual-env` pointed to the correct python location (Because I didn't change my python).

But still I needed to run the same commands to fix the broken links:

```
gfind ~/.virtualenvs/my-virtual-env/ -type l -xtype l -delete
virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/my-virtual-env
```

(You can install gfind with Homebrew)

And of course credit to the author.