# Aborted virtualenv, broken reference for python3

Tags: python

I ran the command `virtualenv venv` and aborted it halfway, and now, whenever I open a new terminal (Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2), I see the message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/don/anaconda3/bin/python
  Reason: image not found

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
```

(Even though I uninstalled `zsh` quite awhile ago; not sure how it's still here).

I can't be sure exactly how this new behaviour occurred, though. Aborting the `virtualenv venv` call was just the *last thing I did*, not necessarily the cause of the issue.

### Issues

- When I try to initialize Jupyterlab (i.e. using `$ jupyter lab`) I get the same error; the same thing happens for `jupyter notebook` (however, note the new line `Abort trap 6`):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/don/anaconda3/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

- Notably, the `(base)` environment (provided by `conda`) that initializes by default whenever I open a new terminal is no longer there. See [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html), section "Managing Environments".

There's a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs), but the root causes don't appear to be similar (I wasn't downloading anything new...I think).

Comment: Have you tried restarting your entire computer? That tends to fix random bugs like this, for whatever reason.

Comment: Yup, restarted. Problem persisted.