# How to get installed package from broken virtual environment python

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I had venv that installed Django and python version3.8. After upgrading my ubuntu my virtual environment doesn't work anymore and it doesn't recognize the pip command and it returns:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

After searching I found out the virtual environment is broken after upgrading and the best way is to remove venv directory and create again and install your packages again but I don't have my installed package list (using pip freeze > list.txt) so now how can I get installed package list from the broken virtual environment?
I can see the list of directories here:

```
$ ls venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
```

but I don't have it

Comment: I think, this maybe linking error which mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs/25947333#25947333. Could you share `$HOME/.virtualenvs/`

Comment: it's: $ ls $HOME/.virtualenvs
ls: cannot access '/home/mrg/.virtualenvs': No such file or directory

Comment: What do you mean you can see list of dirs but you don't have it?
site-packages should be still inside the venv dir, restore the list manually, and let it be a lesson to use something like poetry in the future (or keeping the requirements list updated)
Yes, that's partially a pip fault for being so basic and not keeping a ready list of what was added with it, but you are also responsible to make sure you have your requirements down.